# SWT Table: Cannot retrieve data from table created with TableEditor

Tags: java, swt

I'ma having an issue retrieving data from the table that I've created. It displays a check box, string (taken from all_mapping_objects which is added first) and drop down combo with values 0.0 to 1.0. How do I retrieve the all the values once they have been edited in the table, i.e. check box boolean, string value and combo value.

Tried some variations of `TableItem[] items = table.getItems()` but I only get back empty values.

```
final Table table = new Table(sectionsInfo, SWT.BORDER | SWT.MULTI | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL);
              table.setLinesVisible(true);
               InfogridData = new GridData();
                InfogridData.horizontalSpan = 4;
                InfogridData.horizontalAlignment = GridData.BEGINNING;
                InfogridData.horizontalAlignment = GridData.FILL;
                InfogridData.grabExcessHorizontalSpace = true;
                InfogridData.verticalAlignment = GridData.BEGINNING;
                InfogridData.verticalAlignment = GridData.FILL;
                InfogridData.grabExcessVerticalSpace= true;


                TableColumn column = new TableColumn(table, SWT.NONE);
                column.setWidth(500);

                TableColumn column2 = new TableColumn(table, SWT.NONE);
               column2.setWidth(50);

               table.setLayoutData(InfogridData);


              for (int i = 0; i < all_mapping_objects.size(); i++) {
                new TableItem(table, SWT.NONE);
              }
              TableItem[] items = table.getItems();



              for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                TableEditor editor = new TableEditor(table); //defines editor which controls objects put in 


                CCombo combo = new CCombo(table, SWT.NONE | SWT.READ_ONLY);
                editor.grabHorizontal = true;


                  for (float me = 0; me <= 10; me++) {
                    combo.add("" + me/10);                      
                  }

                combo.setText("1.0");

                editor.setEditor(combo, items[i], 1); // sets the column
                editor = new TableEditor(table);


                Button button = new Button(table, SWT.CHECK);


                button.setText(all_mapping_objects.get(i).getTextf()); // mapping objects written to the table

                button.pack();
                editor.minimumWidth = button.getSize().x;
                editor.horizontalAlignment = SWT.LEFT;
                editor.setEditor(button, items[i], 0); // sets the column



              }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use SelectionListener on `Button ( SWT.CHECK)` and similarly for `CCombo`. I suggest you to start using `TableViewer` instead working with SWT Table.